# Java array parsing string and int

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I am trying to write a program that has 2 arrays, both fixed to value 10.

The program should ask user for a name (string) 10 times and the age of each name (integer) 10 times

This is until either the array is full (10 names and ages have been entered, or the user enters the word 'done')

Then print out the names and associated age of each as well as the youngest and oldest member.

How would I limit the array to 10 items of type string, instead of the user deciding (that the code is currently doing)

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameAge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    

        System.out.print("Enter number of elements to be sorted: ");
        String numElements = input.nextLine();

        String[] num = new String[Integer.parseInt(numElements)];

        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(numElements); i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter name " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            num[i] = input.nextLine();
        }

        for(String element : num) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Just use a `for` loop to iterate 10 times, and prompt the user each time for a name and age.  If the user chooses to quit, use the `break` statement to quit the loop.

Comment: i < Integer.parseInt(...) becomes i < 10. Or whatever you want the terminating condition to be. And then of course you then get rid of the part where you ask the user for the item count, unless you want to give the user the illusion of power, because sometimes it's kind of fun to build up a user's self confidence then tear it down again. It'll help them later in life.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an `ArrayList` to have a dynamic size of the list which isn't possible with a String[]. The program loops 10 times and stops after that, or in case the user enters "done" as a name (using `break;`). I'm saving the data as a `Pair` which makes it simple to associate the data.

```
import javafx.util.Pair;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameAge {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Pair<String, Integer>> names = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter name " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            String line = input.nextLine();
            if (line.equals("done")) break;
            System.out.print("Enter age for user " + (i + 1)+ ": ");
            Integer age = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
            names.add(new Pair<String, Integer>(line, age));
        }
        names.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue for using a while loop in place of a break (because I have an aversion to breaks).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numTried = 1;
        boolean stop = false;
        String entry = "";

        String[] num = new String[10];

        while(numTried <= 10 && !stop){
            System.out.print("Enter name " + numTried + ": ");
            entry = input.nextLine();
            if(entry.toUpperCase().equals("DONE")){
                stop = true;
            }else{
                num[numTried - 1] = entry;
            }

            numTried ++;
        }

        for(String s : num){
            if(!(s == null)){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Loop through until done is entered 10 entries have been entered. Instead of checking just for "done" I've also put in a check for `entry.toUpperCase.equals("DONE")` to allow for case insensitivity. With an array as well, it's also worth checking for `null` when outputting if you don't intend to fill it.

As an aside: don't forget to close scanners when you're finished with them!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `max_age` and `min_age` is only one. And I use `class Person` to organize `name` and `age` information.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameAge {
class Person{
    String name;
    int age;

    Person(String name,int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

private final int MAX_NUMS = 10;
private final String END_FLAG = "done";
private List<Person> personList = new LinkedList<Person>();

public void process(){
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     Person oldestPerson = new Person(null,Integer.MIN_VALUE);
     Person youngestPerson = new Person(null,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
     System.out.println("input name and age, split them by space");
     int number = 1;
     while(number<=MAX_NUMS){
         String curLine = scan.nextLine();
         if(curLine.toLowerCase().trim().equals(END_FLAG)){
             break;
         }
         else{
             String[] strs = curLine.split(" ");
             String name = strs[0];
             int age = Integer.valueOf(strs[1]);
             Person newPerson = new Person(name,age);
             personList.add(newPerson);
             if(oldestPerson.age<newPerson.age){
                 oldestPerson = newPerson;
             }
             if(youngestPerson.age>newPerson.age){
                 youngestPerson = newPerson;
             }
         }
     }
     scan.close();
     for(Person p :personList){
         System.out.println(p.name+"  "+p.age);
     }
     System.out.println("yougest Person:" + youngestPerson.name+" "+youngestPerson.age);
     System.out.println("oldest Person:" + oldestPerson.name+" "+oldestPerson.age);
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     NameAge na = new NameAge();
     na.process();
  }    
}
```